# Transforming XML into html table with too many unknowns

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I have this excerpt of a very large XML file with a lot of unknowns. This XML file contains numerous conceptGrps that each can contain various numbers of languageGrps/languages, which in turn can contain various numbers of terms.

```
<mtf>
  <conceptGrp>
    <concept>1</concept>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="DE" type="Deutsch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>Abbildung</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="PL" type="Polnisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>ilustracja</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="RU" type="Russisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>иллюстрация</term>
      </termGrp>

      <termGrp>
        <term>рисунок</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="CS" type="Tschechisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>vyobrazení</term>

        <descripGrp>
          <descrip type="Autor">MK</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>
  </conceptGrp>
</mtf>
```

I would need an html table that caters to those various possibilities. The form of the table should be:

For each language (no matter how many) a separate row and for each term a separate row – as this: It is important that if there are more than 1 terms that they are treated as synonyms and show up in the same row as in the example below.

```
Concept Deutsch Polnisch    Russisch    Tschechisch

1   Abbildung   ilustracja  иллюстрация vyobrazení

1                           рисунок
```

My problem: Sometimes the first languageGrp has more than 1 terms, sometimes the third, … I tried to group the conceptGrps together and have no problem in going the complicated way-) Here is my version that works but I would have to adapt that to each new file since I can never know how many languages, terms, … there might be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="mtf">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Terminologie</h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html> 
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="conceptGrp">
<xsl:for-each select=".">
<table>

<tr> <!--Zeile 1-->
<td>Konzept-ID</td>
<xsl:for-each select="languageGrp">
<td><xsl:value-of select="language/@type"/></td> <!--Spalte2-->
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>

<tr> <!--Zeile 2-->
<td><xsl:value-of select="concept"/></td> <!--Spalte1-->
<xsl:for-each select="languageGrp//termGrp[1]">
<td><xsl:value-of select="term"/></td> <!--Spalte2-->
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>

<xsl:if test="languageGrp//termGrp[2]">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="concept"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="languageGrp[1]//termGrp[2]/term"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="languageGrp[2]//termGrp[2]/term"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="languageGrp[3]//termGrp[2]/term"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="languageGrp[4]//termGrp[2]/term"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:if>

</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could someone give me a push in a more elegant, global way? This would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was the best design I could come up with, but I think it does everything you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kLang" match="languageGrp" use="language/@lang" />
  <xsl:variable name="uniqueLangs"
                select="/mtf/conceptGrp/languageGrp
                  [generate-id() =  generate-id(key('kLang', language/@lang)[1])]" />

  <xsl:template match="mtf">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Terminologie</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <!--Zeile 1-->
            <td>Konzept-ID</td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$uniqueLangs" mode="header"/>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="conceptGrp" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="languageGrp" mode="header">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="language/@type"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="conceptGrp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="languageGrp" mode="maxGroup">
      <xsl:sort select="count(termGrp)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="languageGrp" mode="maxGroup">
    <!-- Only use the first group out of the sorting (most termGrps) -->
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="termGrp" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="termGrp">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="currConcept" select="../.." />
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$currConcept/concept"/>
      </td>
      <!-- Iterate through all of the distinct languages -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$uniqueLangs">
        <td>
          <!-- Get the term for the current language and position,
                 within the current concept -->
          <xsl:value-of 
            select="$currConcept/languageGrp
                       [language/@lang = current()/language/@lang]
                          /termGrp[$pos]/term"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Terminologie</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Konzept-ID</td>
        <td>Deutsch</td>
        <td>Polnisch</td>
        <td>Russisch</td>
        <td>Tschechisch</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Abbildung</td>
        <td>ilustracja</td>
        <td>иллюстрация</td>
        <td>vyobrazení</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>рисунок</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your original attempt looked like it was putting each concept into a separate table, but was that intentional?  Did you want each concept in a different table with just the languages for that concept, or all the concepts in a single table with all available languages?

Comment: Dear JLRishe, I cannot thank you enough. That is (nearly-) exactly what I nedded. No wonder I was stumbling in the dark. I just thought I have scrathed the surface of xslt - there you go. ... Well

Comment: Dear JLRishe, I cannot thank you enough. That is what I nedded.
In answer to your question: I put each concept into a separate table, but only because I thought it would be easier for me. But your solution is waht I really need. 
Just one more detail (for you, at least, for me it would be overwehleming):
As you can see in the original xml, each termGrp might have various descripGrp giving extra information about the author, context, ... of each term. Would it be possible to have that information as well in such a tabular form that the output table has an extra column for each descrip type?

Comment: @user1633701 Glad to help. So to make sure I understand your new request correctly, you want every language to have an extra column where the description info can go, so instead of the 5 columns in your example, there would instead be 9 columns. Is that correct? Perhaps you could give an example of how you would like that displayed?

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. The results should look like this ( depending on available descriptions) and the content of each description right next to the respective term (one term might be preferred, one might be forbidden)

Con. Deutsch Polnisch Status Kontext Russisch Tschechisch 


Written on my mobile with a far too small keyboard-)

Comment: How that went through. I will be on the road until Friday and will do better with the example. So all in all the same table as you provided plus right next to each language and descrip types (might be 5, might be none) and the content as eg "forbidden" right next to the respective term. Ever so grateful, Michael

Comment: Hi, as promised here the desired result:
(there might be various types of descrip for all or just some terms in a termGrp, and that for any languageGrp)
`…
<descripGrp>
    <descrip type="Autor">MK</descrip>
    <descrip type="Kontext">Marketing</descrip>
</descripGrp>
…`
Result:

`Concept Tschechisch Autor Kontext
1 vyobrazení MK Marketing`

So, exactly as you guessed. Each language might have various different extra columns with descrip types. Thanks again a million times.

Comment: @user1633701 Ok, I think I understand now.  This seems fairly complicated so I will try this within the next few days.  Sorry to keep you waiting.

Comment: Don't be sorry, you have done more for me than I dreamed of. Glad this is complicated for you, too_) Imagine what I must be thinking. In the meantime I will get to my books and try to understand what you were doing. Take care, have a great weekend and whenever I can do something for you (apart from xslt, of course), let me know.

Comment: @user1633701 I think I've thought up a way to do this, and will give it a try tomorrow morning (it's nighttime here). Since the original question is resolved, could you mark this question as answered and open up a separate one about the additional part, referring back to this question? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will certainly try to do that.

Comment: I have opened a new question "Transforming xml into html table with too many unknowns Follow-Up". Cannot wait to hear what you came up with-) Thanks a million in advance