# "Transforming xml into html table with too many unknowns" Follow-Up

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

This is part 2 of the post "[Transforming xml into html table with too many unknowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710531/transforming-xml-into-html-table-with-too-many-unknowns/14711823#comment20711921_14711823)"
In addition to creating an html table with different rows for each language, I'd need for each language a different row containing information from descripGrp. Here is the excerpt from the original XML file with 1 descripGrp for the language "CS"

```
<mtf>
  <conceptGrp>
    <concept>1</concept>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="DE" type="Deutsch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>Abbildung</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="PL" type="Polnisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>ilustracja</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="RU" type="Russisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>иллюстрация</term>
      </termGrp>

      <termGrp>
        <term>рисунок</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="CS" type="Tschechisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>vyobrazení</term>

        <descripGrp>
          <descrip type="Autor">MK</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>
  </conceptGrp>
</mtf>
```

The "descripGrp" can have various "types" and might be present for each "languageGrp/termGrP" or might be missing all together. Thanks to JLRishe who provided an excellent answer to the first problem, the first question is answer, but the addition mentioned here is still open. Thanks for your input. Very, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kLang" match="languageGrp" use="language/@lang" />
  <xsl:key name="kDescrip" match="descrip"
           use="concat(../../../language/@lang, '+', @type)" />
  <xsl:variable name="uniqueLangs"
                select="/mtf/conceptGrp/languageGrp
                  [generate-id() =  generate-id(key('kLang', language/@lang)[1])]" />
  <!-- A set of the first item of each <descrip>, grouped by @lang and @type -->
  <xsl:variable name="uniqueDescrip"
                select="/mtf/conceptGrp/languageGrp/termGrp/descripGrp/descrip
                  [generate-id() = 
                     generate-id(key('kDescrip', 
                        concat(../../../language/@lang, '+', @type))[1])]" />

  <xsl:template match="mtf">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Terminologie</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <!--Zeile 1-->
            <td>Konzept-ID</td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$uniqueLangs" mode="header"/>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="conceptGrp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="languageGrp" mode="maxGroup">
      <xsl:sort select="count(termGrp)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="languageGrp" mode="header">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="language/@type"/>
    </td>
    <xsl:apply-templates
          select="$uniqueDescrip[../../../language/@lang = 
                             current()/language/@lang]"
          mode="header" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="descrip" mode="header">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="languageGrp" mode="maxGroup">
    <!-- Only use the first group out of the sorting (most termGrps) -->
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="termGrp" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="termGrp">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../concept"/>
      </td>
      <!-- Iterate through all of the distinct languages -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$uniqueLangs" mode="item">
        <xsl:with-param name="currConcept" select="../.." />
        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="languageGrp" mode="item">
    <xsl:param name="currConcept" />
    <xsl:param name="pos" />

    <xsl:variable name="matchingTermGrp"
                  select="$currConcept/languageGrp[language/@lang = 
                                                   current()/language/@lang]
                                                   /termGrp[$pos]" />
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="$matchingTermGrp/term"/>
    </td>
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="$uniqueDescrip[../../../language/@lang = current()/language/@lang]"
      mode="value">
      <xsl:with-param name="termGrp" select="$matchingTermGrp" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="descrip" mode="value">
    <xsl:param name="termGrp" />
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="$termGrp/descripGrp/descrip[@type = current()/@type]" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input XML:

```
<mtf>
  <conceptGrp>
    <concept>1</concept>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="DE" type="Deutsch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>Abbildung</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="PL" type="Polnisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>ilustracja</term>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="RU" type="Russisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>иллюстрация</term>
        <descripGrp>
          <descrip type="Other">Sales</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
      </termGrp>

      <termGrp>
        <term>рисунок</term>
        <descripGrp>
          <descrip type="Other">Marketing</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>

    <languageGrp>
      <language lang="CS" type="Tschechisch"/>

      <termGrp>
        <term>vyobrazení</term>

        <descripGrp>
          <descrip type="Autor">MK</descrip>
          <descrip type="Kontext">Marketing</descrip>
        </descripGrp>
      </termGrp>
    </languageGrp>
  </conceptGrp>
</mtf>
```

This produces:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Terminologie</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Konzept-ID</td>
        <td>Deutsch</td>
        <td>Polnisch</td>
        <td>Russisch</td>
        <td>Other</td>
        <td>Tschechisch</td>
        <td>Autor</td>
        <td>Kontext</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Abbildung</td>
        <td>ilustracja</td>
        <td>иллюстрация</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>vyobrazení</td>
        <td>MK</td>
        <td>Marketing</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>рисунок</td>
        <td>Marketing</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My deepest and endless gratitude. It works perfectly!! That's what I needed. Many, many thanks. What would I have done....

Comment: Haha, glad to help.  Please remember to mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark icon next to it. Thanks!